# Fail to load ip_conntrack_tftp in iptables

Tags: iptables, centos7, tftp

sytemd says:

> iptables: Loading additional modules: ip_conntrack_tftp [FAILED]

I didn't find any solutions for Centos7. For Centos prior to 7 it seems to work without problems. lsof etc. doesn't exit for Centos7.

Tftp server works, but there are some problems accessing it through firewalls.

What can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 # modprobe ip_conntrack_tftp
```

and see the logged errors if any

Answer (score 0):

It's solved. the ip_conntrack_tftp module was not compiled for my kernel version.
After doing this, iptables loads without errors.